# Moodle - Why Default Dashboard Page?

Tags: moodle

I was going through the Moodle documentation for setting default dashboard with few blocks on student page. I was surprised that it is not working as provided in the documentation. https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Dashboard#Setting_the_default_Dashboard_for_new_users

Scenario - I want to have one additional block (Random Glossary) available for all users with "authenticated user" role.

I tried following:

1. Logged in with Administrator
2. then clicked on Site Administrator->Appearance->Default Dashboard Page
3. Turned on Block Editing
4. Added new Random Glossary Block from "Add a block"
5. It got added successfully. But when I checked it on actual dashboard it didn't show me.

Moodle is great LMS if we exclude "documentation". Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing the Default Dashboard Page will only update for new users. If you want to be able to see this change for existing users, they will each need reset their dashboards back to the default.

Fortunately in Moodle 3.0 is the feature as an admin to force this reset for all current users.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I would be more than happy if they release newer and improved version soon. Much needed. Thanks!!!